# Position in front of the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

So what I need is to get the `Camera.main.transform.position` in front of the camera depending on its direction. I have searched everywhere but for some reason I just can't find the solution.

I tried using `transform.forward` in a very ill-thought-out way but that didn't work. Nothing I am doing seems to be working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just add the direction and distance to the given position:

```
// In general should cache this reference as "Camera.main" is quite expensive 
var camera = Camera.main.transform;
var position = camera.position + camera.forward * desiredDistance;
```